# "Undefined function node_delete_multiple()"

Tags: drupal-7

```
// Bootstrap Drupal
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once 'includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
function deleteBillNodes()
{
  $results = db_select('node', 'n')
              ->fields('n', array('nid'))
              ->condition('type', array('bill'), 'IN')
              ->execute();
  foreach ($results as $result) 
  {
    $nids[] = $result->nid;
  }

  if (!empty($nids)) 
  {
    node_delete_multiple($nids);
  }
}   
echo "Removing bill nodes from database\n";
deleteBillNodes();
```

I am getting, "Call to undefined function node_delete_multiple()."

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It's because Drupal requires a single constant to be defined (`DRUPAL_ROOT`) before the bootstrap can be run. Just put this before your call to `drupal_bootstrap()`:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
```

This is how Drupal itself does it, the only code lines in `index.php` are:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());

require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I did have define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd()) in there, I just forgot to put it in. Do I need menu_execute_active_handler?

Comment: You shouldn't do, I've just tried your code on a test site and it works, `node_delete_multiple` runs fine. Is this being run on an *installed* Drupal site?

Comment: This is truly odd, I don't think this happened in drupal 7.8

Comment: I'm not really sure what to say sorry, if `node_delete_multiple` isn't found then `node.module` isn't being included and that would probably indicate some sort of problem with the installation

Comment: It seems to be caused by the domain module. (I had to add a line to settings.php). I removed this line and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing fast404 from settings.php and clear cache?
If this is the solution it is time to post it on drupal.org bug page had the same problems on [libristranieri.com](http://libristranieri.com)